# unit test c# mock interface composed inside another interface

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit.net

I'm a novice to coding.

I have a class, `A`:

```
public class A 
{
    public InterfaceB _b;   

    public A() 
    {  
        _b = new B(); 
    } 

    public string functionA() 
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(_b.GetId())) 
            return String.Empty;
        else if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(_b.GetKey())) 
            return String.Empty;
        else  
            return _b.GetToken(); 
    } 
} 

public interface InterfaceB 
{    
    string GetId();   
    string GetKey(); 
    string GetToken();
}
```

I want to test `functionA` where I can penetrate into all the three method of `interfaceB`. In my unit test, I create an instance of class `A` and when I call it I'm not able to set the behavior of class `B`.

It keeps hitting the db, however I need it for other test cases.

How do I completely mock this so that I can test the entire logic?

Comment: You will need a constructor on `A` that takes an `InterfaceB` as a parameter, then you can either directly pass a mocked object `InterfaceB` to that constructor or set it up for injection if you are using DI, even if only for that test.

Answer (score 4):

To be able to test `A` and mock interface `InterfaceB` you have to write `A` so that it is not responsible for creating an instance of `InterfaceB`. Instead it receives an instance of `InterfaceB` through its constructor.

You'll see this pattern over and over again:

```
public A() 
{  
    private readonly InterfaceB _b;

    public A(InterfaceB b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }

    public string functionA() 
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(_b.GetId())) return String.Empty;
        else if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(_b.GetKey())) return String.Empty;
        else  return _b.GetToken(); 
     } 
}
```

This is called dependency injection. It means that a class's dependency is "injected" into it rather than that class creating it. When we inject into the constructor like this we also call it "constructor injection", but commonly it's just "dependency injection." And being able to mock interfaces like what you're asking about is one of the reasons why we use it.

A few key details:

- Because `InterfaceB` is passed to the constructor, nothing in `A` ever "knows" what the actual implementation is. It could be anything. As a result, `A` is never tied to any concrete implementation. (That's why you can "mock" `InterfaceB`.)
- The field `_b` is `readonly`. That's not strictly necessary, but it means that `_b` can only be set from the constructor and never changed again. That emphasizes that `A` only *receives* this and uses it. This class never controls what `_b` is. Whatever *creates* `A` determines what that value is.

Now when you're writing a unit test you can create mocked implementations of `InterfaceB` that do exactly what you want, like

```
public class MockedInterfaceB : InterfaceB
{
    private string _id;
    private string _key;
    private string _token;

    public MockedInterfaceB(string id, string key, string token);
    {
       _id = id;
       _key = key;
       _token = token;
    }
    public string GetId() {return _id};   
    public string GetKey() {return _key}; 
    public string GetToken() {return _token};
}
```

And then in your unit test you can use that implementation:

```
var testA = new A(new MockedInterfaceB("myid","mykey","mytoken"));
```

You can also use tools like [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) to create those mocks more easily.

When you hear of dependency injection it's often in the context of a dependency injection container like Castle Windsor, Autofac, or Unity. Those are useful tools for helping you to make dependency injection work. They're worth learning about. But dependency injection is really just about how you write the classes, like in the example above where we "inject" the dependency (`InterfaceB`) into class `A`.

Comment: Awesome Scott! the Id,key and Token are present in a table B in sql. I would like to simulate several scenarios like empty, non-zero and zero id. 64bit keys..However I dont want to write an extra constructor with InterfaceB as parameter as I am dependency injecting it and would prefer not to touch source code also I would like to check it in part of CI.   When using Moq, can I create two separate mocks IA and IB and set up expectations and inject one moq into another when B is composed in A?. How to achieve this, if so?

Comment: If you need that sort of backwards compatibility then make the constructor parameter optional and supply a default. You can "manually" compose your classes for testing if needed. Create one object and insert the object you want into it for one test, and inject the other one for the other test. You can write methods to compose the test objects for you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, by using [Typemock](https://www.typemock.com) it's possible to test your method without changing your source code.
You will be able to mock B as a future instance before you create an instance of A, then you can just modify B's method behavior.

For example:

```
[TestMethod,Isolated]
public void AllBMethodReturnStrings_WillReturnSuccess()
{
    // Arrange
    // Mocking future B's instance
    var fakeIB = Isolate.Fake.NextInstance<B>();
    var realA = new A();

    Isolate.WhenCalled(()=> fakeIB.GetId()).WillReturn("fakeID");
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeIB.GetKey()).WillReturn("fakeKey");
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeIB.GetToken()).WillReturn("success");

    // Act
    var result = realA.functionA();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("success", result);
}
```